# AppendChild in a for-loop (node transfer)

Tags: c#, xml

I am a beginner in c#, so don't expect a lot from me...

How can I transfer nodes from one xml file to another and store it in the new xml file using c#?

The procedure I took was the following:

1. Load 2 xml files by using variablename.load(filepath)
2. Creating XmlElements which store root node of the imported xml-files.
3. Nested for-loop across the nodes in the xml files.
4. If nodes of the documents are the same, don't do anything
   Else: Remove the content of the previous XML file and update it with the content of the new XML-file

Apparently implementing appendChild results in a System.NullReferenceException: error

Comment: *Apparently implementing appendChild results in a System.NullReferenceException: error* -- then please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the code that doesn't work along with sample XML.  See [ask], specifically *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: That being said, if you are using `XmlDocument`, you may need to use [`XmlDocument.ImportNode(XmlNode, Boolean)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode?view=net-6.0).  But `XmlDocument` isn't really recommended any more, `XDocument` and LINQ-to-XML are much easier to work with.